# Azure DevOps Test Case Questions

Tags: azure, testing, azure-devops

I have a couple of things I have been trying to work out with no success.

I am using Azure DevOps in the cloud not locally.

1. Is it possible to simply paste screen captures into Test Case Steps.
2. When running manual test cases the Runner header displays an icon to Show Description, where do I enter this description in the test case, I have tried the Summary Tab Description with no success.

[Image of description issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQLUS.png)

Answer (score 1):

Andy put me on the right track, I had to extract the process associated with my project then modify the TestCase.xml. I had to change the FieldName from using Microsoft.VSTS.Common.DescriptionHtml to System.Description

Answer (score 0):

> Q1: Is it possible to simply paste screen captures into Test Case Steps.

No, copy/paste screen captures is not supported in Test Case Steps, we can only attach the screenshots as attachments.

> Q2: Where do I enter this description in the test case, I have tried
>   the Summary Tab Description with no success.

Yes, you can enter the description in Summary Tab, make sure you have saved the test case after entering the description. Tested on my side and everything works as expected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I figured as much with the pasting images, not a good solution. Makes it very tedious. The solution you described for the description is what I was doing, however I did go back and retry to make sure It was saved and still have the same issue.

Comment: I added a link to original post as I cannot embedded an image with the issue

Comment: @SimonBillinghurst Seems you have customized the `Test Case` work item type definition file, as you can see from my screenshot no symbol `&` in front of `Description`, but in your test case it has... That might be the root cause. Please check if this issue occurs on other team projects, you can also create a new team project to check if it works...

Comment: I did notice this difference, but as I am the only person who has worked in this space for our organisation I am sure I have not created any custom templates. That being said this project has migrated through several iterations of TFS -> VSTS - DevOps perhaps that has caused an issue.

Comment: @SimonBillinghurst Yeah, that might be the cause, so you can try to check and modify the `Test Case` work item type definition file, just remove the symbol `&`, then try it again to check if that works.

Comment: Any hints on how to modify the test case work item definition file, seeing its in azure i presume I dont have access to the file directly.

Comment: @SimonBillinghurst Well, for Azure DevOps you need to create an inherited process, then custom and using it, please see [Customize a project using an inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav) for details.

Comment: Never mind, I worked it out, exported the process, extracted the zip, modified the TestCase.xml file, zipped the process, imported the process again.Trouble is it didn't fix the problem. The & sign is gone but no description being displayed when running the test case. I might put in a MS Premier support call, thanks for all your efforts Andy/

Comment: @SimonBillinghurst You are welcome, if you resolved the issue you could post the solution here for reference. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.